# IndexError: index out of range in self LSTM

Tags: python, nlp, lstm, embedding

This is my code and I am getting this error, however I can't figure out how to fix it! Please help! Thank you

```
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
def init(self, max_words, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_classes, dropout_prob):
super(LSTMModel, self).init()
self.embedding = nn.Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim)
self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_prob)
self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, batch_first=True)
self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, num_classes)
```

```
def forward(self, x):
    embedded = self.dropout(self.embedding(x))
    lstm_output, _ = self.lstm(embedded)
    last_hidden_state = lstm_output[:, -1, :]
    logits = self.fc(last_hidden_state)
    return logits

def new_model_LSTM(max_words, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_classes, dropout_prob): 
model = LSTMModel(max_words, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_classes, dropout_prob) 
return model
```

```
# Define the training loop parameters
def train(model, train_loader, optimizer, loss_fn, device):
    model.train()
    result = []
    for data, target in train_loader:
        data, target = data.to(device).long(), target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = loss_fn(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        y_pred_train = torch.argmax(output.float(), dim=1) 
        result.extend(y_pred_train.squeeze().tolist())
    return result
```

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

```
max_words = 5000
embedding_dim = embedding_dim
hidden_dim = 10
num_classes = 3
dropout_prob = 0.5

update_model = new_model_LSTM(max_words, embedding_dim , hidden_dim, num_classes, dropout_prob).to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(update_model.parameters())
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

update_model

num_epochs = 3
batch_size = 3
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    result = train(update_model, train_loader, optimizer, loss_fn, device)
    print(result)

print(range)
```

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-f64e659e860c> in <module>
14 batch_size = 3
15 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
---> 16     result = train(update_model, train_loader, optimizer, loss_fn, device)
17     print(result)
18

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
2208         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
2209         *no_grad_embedding_renorm*(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2210     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
2211
2212

IndexError: index out of range in self

I have tried to find the error in the. range but. I cannot

Answer (score 0):

you should ensure that your input data has word indices within the range [0, max_words-1]. You can do this by preprocessing your input text data before feeding it into the model.

```
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, max_words, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_classes, dropout_prob):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_prob)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        embedded = self.dropout(self.embedding(x))
        lstm_output, _ = self.lstm(embedded)
        last_hidden_state = lstm_output[:, -1, :]
        logits = self.fc(last_hidden_state)
        return logits
```